# Magento 2.1: Get All Shipping Carrier in frontend checkout/cart page

Tags: magento-2.1, shipping-methods

I create one module for restrict shipping method based on customer.

So i use plugin for after method in my custom module.

I got all method in `var_dump($group_info)` (app/code/Test/Shipping/Plugin/Shipping.php) like below `first image` (in response).

Now i want to need this all active method display as like in `second image`.

Here is my helper code.

> app/code/Test/Shipping/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php

    namespace Test\Shipping\Helper;

    use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
    use Test\Shipping\Model\Source\Allshippingmethods;

    class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
    {
        protected $urlInterface;

        protected $scopeConfig;

        protected $_storeManager;

        protected $_srModel;

        protected $_asm;

        protected $resourceConnection;

        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface,
            StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
            \Test\Shipping\Model\ShippingFactory $ShippingFactory,
            \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfigObject,
            Allshippingmethods $Allshippingmethods,
            \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resourceConnection
        ) {
            parent::__construct($context);
            $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfigObject;
            $this->urlInterface = $urlInterface;
            $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
            $this->_srModel = $ShippingFactory;
            $this->_asm = $Allshippingmethods;
            $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
        }

        public function getGroupData($id)
        {

            $db = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();
            $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM test_shipping WHERE customer_group=' . $id);
            $row = $result->fetch();
            $values=$row['carriers'];
            $split=explode(",",$values);
            $count = count($split);

            $methods=$this->_asm->toOptionArray();

            foreach ($methods as $j => $inner) {
                if(!empty($inner['value'])){
                    foreach ($inner['value'] as $key => $value) {
                        if (in_array($value['value'], $split)) {      
                           unset($methods[$j]['value'][$key]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return $methods;
        }

        public function getAllMethods()
        {
            $methods=$this->_asm->toOptionArray();

            return $methods;
        }
    }

?>
```

Here is my plugin.

> app/code/Test/Shipping/Plugin/Shipping.php

```
<?php

    namespace Test\Shipping\Plugin;

    use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
    use Test\Shipping\Model\Source\Allshippingmethods;
    use Test\Shipping\Helper\Data;
    use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateCollectorInterface;

    /**
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
     */
    class Shipping
    {
        /**
         * @var \Test\Shipping\Model\ShippingFactory
         */
        //protected $_srModel;

        /**
         * Code of the carrier
         * @var string
         */
        protected $_code='Shipping';
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory
         */
        protected $_rateResultFactory;
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory
         */
        protected $_rateMethodFactory;
        /**
         * Rate result data
         *
         * @var Result
         */
        protected $_result;
        protected $_rateCollector;

        /**
         * @param \Test\Shipping\Model\ShippingFactory $srModel
         */
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
            \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
            \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
            \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
            \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
            \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
            \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directory_list,
            \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resourceConnection,
            RateCollectorInterface $rateCollector,
            \Test\Shipping\Helper\Data $helper,
            array $data = []
        ) { 
            $this->_rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
            $this->_rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
            $this->directory_list = $directory_list;
            $this->cart = $cart;
            $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
            $this->_rateCollector = $rateCollector;
            $this->helper = $helper;
        }

        /**
         * Returns array of key-value pairs of all available methods
         * @return array
         */

        public function getAllowedMethods()
        {
            $group_info=$this->helper->getAllMethods();
            $carriers=array();
            foreach ($group_info as &$carrier) {
                $carriers[$group_info['label']]=$group_info['label'];
            }
            return $carriers;
        }

        public function getResult()
        {
           if (empty($this->_result)) {
               $this->_result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();
           }
           return $this->_result;
        }

        /**
         * Collect rates of given carrier
         *
         * @param string $carrierCode
         * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest $request
         * @return $this
         * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
         * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
         */
        public function aroundCollectCarrierRates(\Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping $subject, \Closure $proceed, $carrierCode, $request)
        {
             $result = $proceed($carrierCode, $request);
             $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
             $customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

             if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
                $gid = $customerSession->getCustomerGroupId();
                $group_info = $this->helper->getGroupData($gid);
                var_dump($group_info); //exit; //Here all method get in response and i want to need this all methods
        }

        $result->getResult()->append($group_info);
        return $result;
        }
    }

?>
```

Here in `var_dump($group_info);` **(app/code/Test/Shipping/Plugin/Shipping.php)**

> (First Image) Below output in Response:-

[image]

I want to add all method that i got in response.

**(Second Image)** This method want to in below image:

[image: Second Image]

I want to all response method get in `checkout/cart` page. How it possible ?

Comment: Need answer for this question.

Comment: If you post code, please explain what this code is supposed to be doing, what actually
happens and where you need help. You should not expect us to run the code in our head and
guess the problem. Besides, this response already shows the shipping carriers. Your question is "how to get all shipping carriers". So what exactly is your problem now?

Comment: Check my updated question @fschmengler.

Comment: Hi @payal,did you found any answer for question?I am also looking for same.

Comment: @akgola, yes I found answer for this question.